# Why there is error Route [dataProcessing] not defined?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting below **error** which is for only `product controller`

> Route [dataProcessing] not defined.

In the `product` **controller** I have script as below

```
public function index(){
    $Products = Product::all();
    return view('product-list', ['products' => $Products]); 
}
```

and in the **blade** I am just trying to echo the data

```
{{ $products }}
```

and my **route** is as following

```
Route::get('/product-list', 'ProductController@index');
```

Can someone kindly guide me why there is error even the script if so simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: How **exactly** do you get that error? Is there really no occurence of `dataProcessing` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a reference of named route `dataProcessing` somewhere in project which is not defined. Maybe in blade file or in some other place.

You need to remove that. If I may guess, its somewhere in blade `{{ route('dataProcessing) }}` or when yo are opening a form using Form facade
`route' => ['dataProcessing']`

If you want, yon add the named route reference :

```
Route::get('/product-list', 'ProductController@index')->name('dataProcessing');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears since you don't have any routes which is named as `dataProcessing`.

Try adding a name for your route.

```
Route::get('/product-list', 'ProductController@index')->name('dataProcessing');
```

Answer (score 0):

use compact instead.in order to pass data from the controller to view use 
samples like below:

```
$products = Product::all();
return view("front.article.index", compact("products"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please double check your blade.php file which might that('dataProcessing') route exist on that page.

It will thrown an error if we declare that route in blade but forgot to mention in our web.php file. For example

In blade.php file

```
<a href="{{route('dataProcessing')}}">Sample Code</a>
```

In Web.php file

```
Route::get('dataprocessing', 'somecontroller@somefunction')->name('dataProcessing');
```